# conditional insert sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My procedure

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc]
 @uniqueid  uniqueidentifier,
 @y int

DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
 SELECT TOP 1 @ID = uniqueid FROM tbl_x WHERE y= @y

INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
VALUES
(
   @otherfields
   ,if @ID == null then @uniqueid else @ID -- this is what i want to happen how i do not know
)
```

Now i can do this using if else block like this but i do not want to do it. I want some nice way of coding this

this is what i do not want to do

```
if(@id IS NULL)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
VALUES
(
   @otherfields
   ,@uniqueid 
)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
VALUES
(
   @otherfields
   ,@id 
)
END
```

is there any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  `insert into select` like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
SELECT 
  @otherfields,
  ISNULL(@ID , @uniqueid)
```

Comment: you can combine the two select statements into this to have one statement.  with this you need a table lock to be sure there are no deadlocks or other problems.  With one statement (by combining) the server will take care of it.

Comment: Cool it is working fine. Thanks. I did discover this works as well CASE WHEN .. = null THEN ..  else ..  END. I am adding dots coz comments does not let me enter @

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `IF` into the `SELECT` where you assign the value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyProc]
 @uniqueid  uniqueidentifier,
 @y int

DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
 SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ISNULL(uniqueid,@uniqueid) FROM tbl_x WHERE y= @y

INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
VALUES
(
   @otherfields
   ,@ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CASE while inserting values

```
INSERT INTO tbl_x
(   
    otherfield
    ,uniqueid   
)
VALUES
(
   @otherfields
   ,CASE WHEN @ID IS NULL THEN @uniqueid ELSE @ID END
)
```

or you can also use ISNULL function.